# Object doesn't support property or method 'hubConnection' when running SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm wetting my legs with SignalR, and starting with a simple tutorial.

Problem is, when I run the application, I get the following error message:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hubConnection'

My HTML is as follows:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var test = $.connection.messagesHub;

        test.addNewMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '');
        };

        $('#broadcast').click(function () {
            test.addMessage($('#message').val());
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();

    });
</script>
```

And the Hub's code is:

```
[HubName("messagesHub")]
public class MessagesHub : Hub
{
    public void addMessage(string message)
    {            
        Clients.addNewMessage(message);
    }
}
```

If I try to browse directly to /signalr/hubs, I get the js contents.

What am I missing? I just can't find the problem...

Answer (score 3):

According to [Announcing the Release of SignalR 0.5.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx) hubConnection object is new in v0.5.3 but you are using v0.5.2.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't understand... I don't use the hubConnection object, and yet I get an error related to it, generated by the hubs file. What can cause this?